# Inverse Galois Characteristic p

Tags: number-theory, galois-theory, function-fields, positive-characteristic

I am trying to find any information on the inverse galois problem for F_p[t]. Is there a literature or survey for this problem or any well known counter examples. Thanks :)

Comment: What about $\overline{\Bbb{F}}_p(t)$ ?